# Unable to access a registry key

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-registry

I wondered why some file associations were broken and stumbled upon a nasty problem: I cannot access the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see above, I cannot view its current permissions, nor its owner (which should by `SYSTEM`). And no matter what I tried I'm unable to fix it. Trying to change the owner gives me a permission denied (also when trying from the Administrator account). RegDacl, which seemed to help another user, also aborts with a permission denied error.

Any suggestions how to repair this? If I cannot repair this I guess I have to dump that user account and create a new one. Are there any "diff-like" tools out there to help copy over registry keys?

Comment: Did you open regedit as "run as administrator"?

Answer (score 4):

You need to access the registry as SYSTEM.  From an administrator command prompt, run:

```
psexec -s -i regedit
```

This gives you system level access to the registry keys and you can do ANYTHING.  Be careful.

Comment: You can get PSEXEC [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

Answer (score -1):

You can edit registry with Emergency Boot CD ( http://www.prime-expert.com/ebcd/ ) which ignores key security descriptors and allows access to everything. By copying key security descriptor from root key to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes you can reset its ACL to default.